# Unable to remove unwanted toggle button on custom plugin details page

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue with [**Gift Certificate Creator Plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gift-certificate-creator/). After adding the shortcode `[gift_certificate_form]` on any post/page, we need to submit the form from the front end.

The details are also displayed in WordPress admin area.So when I checked from **`Gift certificate > settings`**. I am getting an unwanted toggle button near to username. I tried adding CSS, to hide but failed. So anyone please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: You CSS doesnt work if you written those in themes style.css.

Comment: can you share a link to have a look for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You CSS doesn't work for admin dashboard if you written those in themes `style.css`.**

You Need to write an add_action to `functions.php`.
And After I checked. I saw `.toggle-row` is the unwanted toggle button near to username **Gift Certificate Creator**. So Use Below Code in themes `functions.php`.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_head', 'my_css');

function my_css() {
  echo '<style>
    .toggle-row {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>';
}
?>
```